# Where can I buy Black V-Neck Tzitzit

Tags: tzitzis

I’m looking to buy high quality, black, V-Neck Tzitzit, with techeilet strings.

I wear black V-neck undershirts, and would be convenient to have the same style for my Tzitzit.

If anyone knows where I could get this done (and Halachically if there are any issues), I would very much appreciate it!

Note: I am sepharadi.

Not opposed to converting my shirts myself and adding the strings, of course under my LOR’s supervision, if anyone has some advice on that.

Comment: In ashkenazi communities, tzitzit are generally only attached to white garments.

Comment: It’s worth noting I’m sepharadi (updated the question), but good to know. is it general practice, or a specific requirement for the white garments?

Comment: There's a relatively minor debate if the non-tekhelet strings should always be white or always match the color of the garment (black, in your case). To avoid any questions ashkenazi custom is to always use white garments.

Comment: I believe the mishna berurah says the beged should be white. Also unsure if this is what you are talking about, but undershirt tzitizis are usually not preferable, as you don't wand the beged (and for sure the strings) to be touching your skin.

Comment: Just a google search away, achi: https://www.ajudaica.com/Adult-Black-T-Shirt-with-Tzitzit/item13683

Answer (score 0):

In [the Mishna Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Fringes.2.8?lang=bi), The Rambam writes:

> When a garment is entirely red, green, or any other color [besides white], its white strands should be made from the same color
> as the garment itself. If it is green, they should be green. If it is
> red, they should be red.Should the garment itself be techelet, its
> white strands should be made from any color other than black, for it
> resembles techelet. He should wind one strand of techelet around all
> the strands, as one does with other tzitzit that are not colored.When a garment is entirely red, green, or any other color

However, in practice I was instructed by my Ashkenazi Rabbi to use white tzizit on my red talit.

Comment: Interesting. Are your talit entirely red?

Comment: Red, with some black and white (Levi flag colors), but predominantly red

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ruling Sephardic opinion of the Rambam is that if the garment is all one color then the fringes should match the color of the garment.

But I have yet to see a kasher source of spun tzit tzit of colored varieties. I've seen Christian ("Messianic Jewish") communities sell colored tzit tzit. But I believe halakha requires they be spun for the sake of the mitzvah by a Jew. Therefore the mitzvah of tzit tzit is not fulfilled by buying from these faithful and well intentioned Christian sources.

Therefore it's my recommendation you buy only white garments to match white strings unless you can find a kasher source for other colored tzit tzit.

Comment: Presumably you could buy white strings and dye them yourself. That shouldn't be too hard.